# I am trying to import a fast food order program and it keeps saying "food_choice" is not defined

Tags: python

I have been trying to fix this and cannot understand. I am supposed to import a module and the module should work on my new Python runner, but it is not working. It keeps saying food_choice is not defined.

Code down below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def show_food_menu():
    """This function only displays the menu"""
    print("Welcome to the General Fast Food")
    print("Press 1 to add pasta to your order $3")
    print("Press 2 to add salad to your order $6")
    print("Press 3 to add sandwich to your order $9")
    print("Press 0 if you don't want any food")

def show_drink_menu():
    """This function only displays the menu"""
    print("Welcome to the General Fast Food")
    print("Press 1 to add orange juice to your order $1")
    print("Press 2 to add water (free) to your order $2")
    print("Press 3 to add soda to your order $3")
    print("Press 0 if you don't want any drink")
    
def show_dessert_menu():
    """This function only displays the menu"""
    print("Welcome to the General Fast Food")
    print("Press 1 to add pie to your order $2")
    print("Press 2 to add cookies to your order $4")
    print("Press 3 to add fruit to your order $6")
    print("Press 0 if you don't want any dessert")
    
def get_user_choice():
    """This function reads the user choice and returns it
    Assume the user will always enter valid values"""
    choice = int(input("Choice: "))
    return choice

def get_total_price(food_choice, drink_choice, dessert_choice):
    """Function calculates the prices
    you need to pass, as a parameter, the choices that the user made
    when ordering their food, drink and dessert
    """
    price = food_choice * 3 + drink_choice * 1 + dessert_choice * 2
    return price

def print_total_price(total_price):
    """this fucntion just prints a friendly message with the
    final price for the customer
    """
    print("Thanks for buying our food. Your bill is $", total_price)
```

The import section that is having the problems:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import module5
from module5 import *
module5.show_food_menu()
module5.show_drink_menu()
module5.show_dessert_menu()
module5.get_user_choice()
module5.get_total_price(food_choice, drink_choice, dessert_choice)
module5.print_total_price(total_price)
```

Comment: I think the error is in your import statement. You import twice: `import module5` imports the module which can be accessed as `module5.show_food_menu()`. But `from module5 import *` imports the modules functions directly into your scripts namespace so they should be available as `show_food_menu()`. Note that such wildcard imports are considered an anti-pattern. Just delete the line and you're good to go.

Comment: @nahalem I tried that and it is still saying food_choice is not defined I can add what the output should look like if that could help you understand a little better?

Comment: Are your functions stored in a file called `module5.py` which is in the same folder as the script you are running?

Comment: @IJeszi you have not defined `food_choice` in your second code snippet. Hence the error!

Answer (score 3):

You are not storing your return values in variables

This is what you want to do

```
import module5
from module5 import *
module5.show_food_menu()
food_choice = module5.get_user_choice()
module5.show_drink_menu()
drink_choice = module5.get_user_choice()
module5.show_dessert_menu()
dessert_choice = module5.get_user_choice()
total_price = module5.get_total_price(food_choice, drink_choice, dessert_choice)
module5.print_total_price(total_price)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you man I really appreciate it, It finally works and I now undertsand!